# How to store user data in .env file in React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, api, environment-variables, private-key

I want the user to store his key and API in .env file. These data will obviously vary from user to user. So every user will have his own set of .env file. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maintainer of [react-natiev-dotenv](https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv) here!

I recently added a feature to use `.env.local` from dotenv flow. Add `.env.local` to your `.gitignore` and ask each user to add their custom API keys in there. I hope this answers your question!